# Xcode swift parse json codable

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to understand the best way to parse a json file with the Codable.

This is the json structure.

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    [10.23, 48.32],
                    [10.24, 48.33],
                    [10.25, 48.34],
                    [10.26, 48.35],
                    [10.27, 48.36]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need is the list of coordinates. I tried to implement this structures but I have some problems.

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let features: [Features]
}

struct Features: Codable {
    let geometry: [Coordinates]
}

struct Geometry: Codable {
    let coordinates: [Coordinates]
}

struct Coordinates: Codable {
    let latitude: [Double]
    let longitude: [Double]
}
```

Then I call the `JSONDecoder` function like this

```
let coordinates = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
```

I think that the error is that the coordinates are in a sublist. I'm new in this world so sorry if the question is a little bit dummy but I haven't find an explanation by my self.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: This is GeoJSON. Use [MKGeoJSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkgeojsondecoder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you were almost there. Try this:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let features: [Feature]
}

struct Feature: Codable {
    let geometry: Geometry
}

struct Geometry: Codable {
    let coordinates: [[Double]]
}
```

and:

```
let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
```

and:

```
for feature in root.features {
    let coords = feature.geometry.coordinates
    print("\(coords)")
}
```

PS: your data seems to be `GeoJSON`. Read-up on Swift GeoJSON and how to decode it.